# Binding Repeater from Class Library

Tags: asp.net, web-services, e-commerce, asprepeater

I have an ecommerce website, wherein user would be able to add product into the cart and move on for the checkout, i have a generic display of the cart in masterpage, so that it remains visible on all the pages.

Now on product page, when user clicks on add to cart button, it should update the cart menu with the quantity of the product in real-time. I am using ajax function for add to cart button on product page, and the function for the ajax resides in a separate class library project.

Could i access the repeater control and rebind it from the webmethod from separate class library.

Here's my code:
Master Page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptShoppingCart" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnMRP" runat="server" Value='<%# double.Parse(Eval("MaximumRetailPrice").ToString()) * int.Parse(Eval("Quantity").ToString()) %>' />
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Image ID="imgProduct" Width="75" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' /></td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-12"><%# Eval("Name") %></div>
                <div class="col-md-12">$<%# double.Parse(Eval("OurPrice").ToString()).ToString("N") %> X <%# Eval("Quantity") %> = $<asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# (double.Parse(Eval("OurPrice").ToString()) * int.Parse(Eval("Quantity").ToString())).ToString("N") %>'></asp:Label></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #e4e7ea;">
                <td style="float:right;"><h2>$<%# SumShoppingValue().ToString("N") %></h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="float:right;"><%# SumShoppingSavings() %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

MasterPage.cs

```
rptShoppingCart.DataSource = _cart.GetShoppingCart();
rptShoppingCart.DataBind();
```

My content page inherits from the webservice class which is a class library and my webservice inherits from UI.Page.

`public class ProductPage : WebMethodLibrary` // This is my content page class declaration.

Webservice: 
`public class WebMethodLibrary : Page` // This is my webservice class declaration.

```
Page currentPage = new Page(); // I created this object, because my webmethod is a static method, hence i cannot use the Master.FindControl, and i am sure, my issue resides here only. Not sure what object need to be created.
Repeater rptShoppingCart = currentPage.Master.FindControl("rptShoppingCart") as Repeater;
rptShoppingCart.DataSource = shoppingDetails.GetShoppingCart();
rptShoppingCart.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a static method in another class

```
Page currentPage = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

Repeater rptShoppingCart = currentPage.Master.FindControl("rptShoppingCart") as Repeater;
rptShoppingCart.DataSource = shoppingDetails.GetShoppingCart();
rptShoppingCart.DataBind();
```

But it is not entirely clear from your question, but if you use an Ajax call to a webmethod and will try to find the Repeater that won't work. A webmethod does not have access to the Page object.

So if you make an ajax call to fill the Repeater you will need a pure JavaScript/jQuery way of displaying the cart items.